# spfielduservaluecollection.remove not working

Tags: 2013, splistitem, spuser

I want to remove the user from the list item from the column of type person or group and it is multi-valued.

My code is:

```
        private void DeleteUserFromList(SPUser userDeleted, string fieldName, SPListItem item, SPWeb sPWeb)
    {
        SPFieldUserValueCollection Users = item[fieldName] as SPFieldUserValueCollection;
        SPFieldUserValue DeletedUserValue = new SPFieldUserValue(sPWeb, userDeleted.ID, userDeleted.LoginName);
        Users.Remove(DeletedUserValue);
        item[fieldName] = Users;
        item.Update();
        item.ParentList.Update();
    }
```

When the code gets executed `SPFieldUserValueCollection` values remain same after `Remove()` i.e. If `SPFieldUserValueCollection` fetches 2 users then they remain 2 after executing Remove() method.

What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of creating a new SPFieldUserValue find the one in the SPFieldValueCollection you want to remove like this:

```
private static void DeleteUserFromList(SPUser userDeleted, string fieldName, SPListItem item, SPWeb sPWeb)
{
    SPFieldUserValueCollection Users = (SPFieldUserValueCollection)item[fieldName];
    SPFieldUserValue DeletedUserValue = Users.First(u => u.LookupId == userDeleted.ID);
    Users.Remove(DeletedUserValue);
    item[fieldName] = Users;
    item.Update();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the below code,

```
SPFieldUserValueCollection fuvc = item[fieldName] as SPFieldUserValueCollection;
foreach (SPFieldUserValue value in fuvc)
{
if (value.LookupId == userDeleted.ID)
{
fuvc.Remove(value);
item[fieldName] = fuvc;
item.Update();
break;
}
}
```

Hope this helps you.